# Is it possible to add data to 2 tables with a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a tables

**MEMBER** 
member_id(using sequence),
member_lastname,
member_firstname,

**BOOKS**
book_num(using sequence),
book_title,
book_author,

**RENTAL**
rent_num(pk fk),
member_id(fk),
rent_date,

**DETAILRENTAL**
rent_num(fk),
detail_fee,
detail_returndate,
detail_duedate,

how do I add these values both in detail rental and rental?

```
member_lastname:Simon
member_id: (base on the last_name inserted)
detail_fee :40
detail_returndate :12-03-2016
detail_duedate:12-01-2016
```

Comment: How do you know the rent_num ?

Comment: by setting the sequence to 10000 and use rent_num_seq.nextvalue @EkinOf

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if the rent_num is auto increment :

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO RENTAL (member_id, rent_date)
SELECT member_id, NOW() FROM MEMBER WHERE member_lastname = 'Simon';
INSERT INTO DETAILRENTAL (rent_num, detail_fee, detail_returndate, detail_duedate) 
VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 40, '12-03-2016', '12-01-2016');
COMMIT;
```